# Panoramio REST API - how to get latitude and longitude?

Tags: api, rest, coordinates, photos, panoramio

I have been creating an implementation where I would want to get the latitude and longitude coordinate values per each of the returned image from Panoramio.

I have seen an example where the REST call returned an object, which contained also the lat&lon values for the photo. E.g. when requesting simply first 10 top listed images.

If I now examine the default input from the Panoramio service, I atleast cannot locate the parameters lat and lon in the result?

Anyone knows why this is and how could I get both the images and the latitude longitude values as supposed?

Cheers
Gary Hamilton
Norway